# MVC - Identity in a separate project - web references needed - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I am trying to decouple the Identity model logic from an MVC project, as it appears in the standard template with Individual Identity.

I have created a class library and copied over the IdentityModels.cs file.

But as I am adding NuGet packages such as Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework to solve the missing references problems, the references list gets filled up with dlls that sound like web libraries, e.g. MS.Owin.Security.Cookies, Newtonsoft.Json, etc. Also, the IdentityModels.cs uses IdentityDbContext, which is contained in MS.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.

My question is: is it possible to completely remove the web-related dlls from the models project to make it "pure" models and business logic, (i.e. to have no references to cookies or Json or aspnet) or is the Identity Framework so tightly integrated with UI and browsers that it is best to leave it inside the MVC project?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. May I ask why you would like to separate it out of the MVC project?

Comment: Like many other people I believe that separating out the models into separate project/assembly is a good practice, for the reasons of keeping business logic separate from the website plumbing. It is obviously easy with generic domain objects, like company/customer/blog post etc. But the Identity Framework consists of models as well, and so it would be logical to keep its models along with all other modes.